# Can anyone tell me how to solve these errors?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, eclipse, jdbc

Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.admin.TimezoneDump.main(TimezoneDump.java:70)

Comment: You ran the application `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.admin.TimezoneDump` that is built in the MySQL Connector/J driver instead of your own application.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a password and try connecting again.

```
GRANT ALL ON <database>.* TO '<user>'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, because the application that the OP is running is using an empty username.